# OK Google with string input? - Android

Tags: android, google-speech-api

Is there a way to send a string to google now and get a response?

Example:

send "What time is it?" and get a string or audio response from google that says "It is 4:32pm."

```
String question = "What time is it?";
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(question);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String converted_text = result.get(0);

        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze the question by your self and get the answer and send it back using the TextToSpeech. For your example : You analyzed the string you find "Time" and you get the time from Android system and you send back the time as string to TextToSpeech.